# How to log Firebase Analytics screen name in a SwiftUI app?

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log screen names in my app but I have like 95% not set in Firebase Analytics.

In `onAppear` for a view I do `Analytics.setScreenName("screenName", screenClass: "screenName")`

Should I do this differently? It seems that Analytics for iOS works in conjunction with `UIViewController`s but since this a SwiftUI app and there is no documentation on how to work with that.

Comment: did you find a better solution in the meantime? I have the same issue

Answer (score 8):

*Update*
This is now possible using the `analyticsScreen` view modifier. See the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/f98724673ddfe90ebb6fcadca321c73817c900d5/FirebaseAnalyticsSwift/Sources/Analytics%2BSwiftUI.swift#L62)

---

We are working on a better solution for this. As you mentioned, the way the view controller hierarchy of a SwiftUI app is made up, this is not entirely trivial to solve, but we've got a couple of ideas.

In the meantime, you might want to try this workaround that some people have suggested on the [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4838):

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
  Analytics.setScreenName("todo_tab", screenClass: String(describing: type(of: self)))
}
```

Comment: thanks @peter-friese, the ticket is closed and it links to a blogpost but the latter does not clearly give recommendation as to how track "screen views" in SwiftUI views. Would you mind pointing us to the Firebase docs?

Comment: I haven't fully understood how to use `.analyticsScreen()` has anyone figure it out?

Comment: Hi Luca, can you be more specific?

Comment: @PeterFriese I'm trying to use it now but it tells me that it is defined on `View` and so may not be available in this scope. Are there any docs for it? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code, @Fogmeister? You can only use this on a View.

Comment: @Luca, you need to be importing FirebaseAnalyticsSwift and not just FirebaseAnalytics.